# Good answers that lead asker to better answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27974641/1454117) and received a good answer. The answerer was able to identify the problem concisely and provide a solution that works to correct the problem. Excellent!

I researched the solution more (now fully understanding the problem I was facing) and found what I believe to be a better solution. I don't want to jip the answerer out of reputation for the help provided, especially since I wouldn't have found this other answer without understanding the actual **problem** which the other answer already covers.

What's the proper etiquette for situations like this?

Seems like I could:

1. Add a second answer of my own and accept that instead (and reference the other answer for a description of the problem).
2. Update the other answer (with the answerer's buy in, of course) to provide more suggestions for resolution.
3. Number 1 plus offer a bounty to the other answer for helping me solve the problem.

Thoughts? Any other good options for handling this type of situation?

Comment: What I've seen most often is the OP upvote and accept the answer that someone else provided and which served as a base for their own answer, and post their own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not be editing another answer to add entirely new content not at all included by the author.

If you have found a different solution to the same problem, you should post it as an answer.  If that solution is derived from another solution, you should cite the content appropriately.

Whether you choose to accept your answer or the other answer is entirely up to you.

If you want to post a bounty to the question and award it to the other answer you're certainly welcome to, but you also have no *obligation* to.