# How acceptable is it to flesh out someone's answer before accepting it?

Tags: discussion

I received an answer that set me on the right path to solve my problem (a path that I would not have otherwise found) but which still required me to do some homework of my own to reach the solution.  In itself, of course, that's a good thing---probably the ideal learning experience.

However, I wasn't sure how to handle acceptance for posterity's sake.  I felt I wanted to accept that user's answer since it had made the crucial link, but also felt the answer wasn't complete enough to help future googlers, and that the accepted answer to this question should be more complete.

It would have felt wrong to use the answerer's suggestion to develop my own solution, post that, and accept my own post (though it's a little academic since the 15 points were a drop in this particular user's ocean anyway). It would also have felt wrong to ask the answerer to spend extra time to elaborate when I'd already figured it out.

What I did was edit the answerer's answer to append working code before accepting, with a comment explaining this.  But in general I guess a good SE citizen should avoid making such substantive changes to other people's answers.

What's the best way to handle such a case?

Comment: OK, I guess this was covered in a thread I didn't find the first time around: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283778/good-answers-that-lead-asker-to-better-answers .  Just thinking out loud. Ignore me.